# Filter for duplicate elements

Tags: java, performance

I wrote code to filter for duplicate elements in an array. I'd like to know your opinion, whether it's efficient at all, or if there's too many objects created, use of both array and list. That's in preparation for an interview. I'm not interested in lambdas (distinct) or helper methods, I'd like to see where I can improve and understand what's efficient or not in what I wrote, also without using Set, HashSet.

```java
public class Duplicate {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        // filter duplicate elements
        int [] arr = {5,4,3,5,4,6,7,8,6};
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        int length = arr.length;
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(arr[0]);
        for(int i =0; i <length-1;i++){
            if(arr[i] != arr[i+1]){
                list.add(arr[i+1]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add the items to a `Set` instead of a `List` to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, without using a set.

Comment: In an interview, the first task would be to fix what is to be accomplished. Is it *filter out* non-unique values, *keep* them, or expunge/keep values *occurring exactly twice*? If it was *keep unique values*, what is the required result? A `Collection` thereof? A `List`? Immutable `Set` (self implemented)? A mutated input array? "Duplicates" replaced with a special `NO_VALUE`, or *unique values compacted to the front*, with their count returned?

Answer (score 2):

This problem is very simple in only a few lines of code, as long as we know what the constraints on the input are:

```
int [] arr = {5,4,3,5,4,6,7,8,6};
int maxPossibleInputValue = 9;
...
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
byte[] tracker = new byte[maxPossibleInputValue + 1];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    if (tracker[arr[i]]++ == 0)
    {
        list.add(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Only works when we know the range of input possible due to memory consumption, but it will be fast - O(n) with only a single heap allocation.

If the value range will exceed memory constraints (i.e. the entire 32 bit int range instead of "all digits under 1000" or such), then we may have to implement our own simple hashset...

i.e.

```
List<Integer> mainRoutine(int[] arr)
{
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    MyNode[] tracker = new MyNode[65536];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        int segment = arr[i] % tracker.length;
        if (tracker[segment] == null) || !tracker[segment].has(arr[i]))
        {
            list.add(arr[i]);
        }
        MyNode newNode = new MyNode(arr[i], tracker[segment]);
        tracker[segment] = newNode;
    }
    return list;
}

...
...

private static class MyNode
{
    private final int val;
    private MyNode child;

    private MyNode(int val, MyNode child)
    {
        this.val = val;
        this.child = child;
    }

    boolean has(int val)
    {
        return (this.val == val) || (child != null && child.has(val);
    }
}
```

Comment: For the scoreboard, one would need to know `minPossibleInputValue` - to be 0 if not subtracting it. `byte[] tracker` "with postincrement" can lead to non-unique values every `Byte.MAX_VALUE - Byte.MIN_VALUE`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the items to a `Set` instead of a `List` to avoid duplicates. That way you delegate to `Set` for uniqueness:

```
int [] arr = {5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 6};

Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

int length = arr.length;

for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    set.add(arr[i]);
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(set.toArray()));
```

Comment: Have you tested this on an array with only one element?

Comment: I copy the loop from the question. Now is fixed.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, without using a Set.

Comment: dnault - Yes, let's take into consideration there's an if statement to filter for that, this is to focus more on the working logic

Answer (score 1):

It may be important to the interviewer that you can find a solution without sorting (I don't know the full context of the interview question), for example if the original order is important or if the elements can not be compared in a sortable way. A solution that would take O(n^2) time but preserve order, and take O(1) space is to go element by element, search the rest of the data structure for a repetition of the current element and removing it. It would take O(n^2) if you used a structure with O(1) removals, such as a linked list.

Comment: No, I don't get a null pointer exception, as it stops one before the length of the array, i + 1 still works.

Comment: @Patrick Oh right, sorry, that was lazy on my part. I’ll edit it so it doesn’t confuse anyone

Comment: If not mutating the input, fill a new sequence (`new ArrayList(arr.length)`). Comparing to the part of the array with either lower or higher than current index  should halve comparison count. Iterating the list of unique values may or may not be faster still, depending on ratio of non/unique value.

Answer (score 1):

> ...or if there's too many objects created, use of both array and list.

There is a quite number of objects created, additionally to the array and the list there is a corresponding `Integer` object created for each `int` from the array to filter. Referring to efficiency (1) between addition and subtraction the later is the efficient operation (2) between sorting the duplicates array and sorting the filtered array the later is the efficient sort.

An improved solution would iterate over the array to filter backwards without sorting it while adds the unique elements to a new array...

```
public class Deduplicate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] toFilter = { 5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 6 };
        System.out.println("Filter: " + Arrays.toString(toFilter) );
        int[] filtered = { };
        for (int i = toFilter.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {

            boolean skippable = false;
            int toFind = toFilter[i];
            for (int j = i - 1; j > -1; j--) {
                if (toFilter[j] == toFind) {
                    skippable = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (skippable) { continue; }

            int length = filtered.length;
            int[] result = new int[length + 1];
            result[0] = toFilter[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                result[j + 1] = filtered[j];
            }
            filtered = result;
        }
        System.out.println(" After: " + Arrays.toString(toFilter));
        System.out.println("Result: " + Arrays.toString(filtered));
    }
}
```

...with the result two unsorted arrays, the array to filter and the resulted array...

> Filter: [5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 6]
>   After: [5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 6]
> Result: [5, 4, 3, 6, 7, 8]

The above is the solution that matches the requirements: filter for duplicates without lambdas nor helper methods efficiently.

Comment: This method is O(n^2), whereas sorting is O(n log n) (or even O(n) for integers in a limited range). And this does always the worst case number of comparisons in a bubble sort, I can’t believe this would be considered efficient.